# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment no longer exists for key f1: index 3

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to understand this exception in order to implement a proper fix.

There's a ViewPager and it uses a FragmentStatePagerAdapter to instantiate 2 fragments via getItem and `MyFragmentClass.newInstance(...)`.

Adapter's getItem looks like this:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = MyFragment2.newInstance(par1);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = MyFragment2.newInstance(par2, par3);
            break;
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

Problem:

When the activity is destroyed, and created again, the adapter is intantiated again, the fragments created again with `MyFragmentClass.newInstance(...)`... but then on this line:

`pager.setAdapter(adapter);`

I get the mentioned exception.

I looked in the source where the exception is thrown, it's this:

```
@Override
public Fragment getFragment(Bundle bundle, String key) {
    int index = bundle.getInt(key, -1);
    if (index == -1) {
        return null;
    }
    if (index >= mActive.size()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Fragement no longer exists for key "
                + key + ": index " + index);
    }
    Fragment f = mActive.get(index);
    if (f == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Fragement no longer exists for key "
                + key + ": index " + index);
    }
    return f;
}
```

So a bundle is passed there, with some state which references my old fragments, but this doesn't correspond to the current state (`mActive`), and the exception is thrown.

I don't understand what's the idea behind this, or which way I'm supposed to instantiate the fragments.

I tried a trick I got from another context:

`pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);`

In order to avoid that the fragments are destroyed when they are off screen (in the case of 2 pages viewpager, although don't know if it works well with state adapter). But don't seems to be related, at least, it doesn't help, still get the same exception.

Catching the exception leads to the pages being blank.

Comment: did you find a working solution for your problem?

Comment: I don't remember, sorry :(

Comment: The question was asked 2 years ago. Nowadays, AppcompatActivity and support fragment are used. Use setRetianInstance(true); and remember to recreate adapter with existing items on orientation. If you don't recreate adapter, it will try to use trashed context which will lead to the crash.

Comment: The same issue is discussed in thread https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54520

Answer (score 70):

This could help -

```
@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}
```

Add the line above in `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

Comment: This works perfectly for dealing with a paging adapter in the back stack. Thanks!

Comment: If you are avoiding `saveState()` you no longer need to use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Then you just have to use `FragmentPagerAdapter` for working

Comment: @Nishad what is not true?

Comment: avoiding `saveState()` for `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is not equivalent of using `FragmentPagerAdapter`. `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` destroys the fragment objects when not in use `FragmentPagerAdapter` does not. By avoiding saveState() we are asking `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to destroy fragments without saving state.

Comment: @Nishad Yeah you're right, but take a look at my comment again. My comment is regard of the answer. `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` by default saves all the data for keeping state and `FragmentPagerAdapter` does not. So instead of using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and override `saveState()` returning null, he can use `FragmentPagerAdapter` which does not implement `saveState()` by default. That's what I meant ;)

Comment: @Lennon `FragmentPagerAdapter` doesn't use `saveState()` because the entire fragment is retained in memory. If you want to avoid that behavior you use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` which only saves state. If you don't want to save anything at all, then you use `FragmentStatepagerAdapter` without saving state; it automatically does not save the `Fragment` in memory.

Comment: It's better to add
`@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return new Bundle();
}`
In my case return null clears viewpager

Comment: You are a life savior, Thank you so much @Mikelis Kaneps

Answer (score 27):

If you don't want the fragments to get reclaimed when they are offscreen, you should be using `FragmentPagerAdapter` and not `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

Comment: what's the difference in this situation ?

Comment: `FragmentPagerAdapter` loads each fragment in memory as it is visited. `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` releases its reference to fragments once they are past the `offscreenPageLimit` parameter.

Comment: so if we set an offscreenpagelimit it wouldn't an issue anymore ? (for the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`)

Comment: No, the original poster was doing something else wrong, such as setting the number of items incorrectly.

Answer (score 20):

**Issue Detail** 
     By default FragmentStatePagerAdapter will save and restore the state of ViewPager. While restore if fragment instance killed due to some reason then FragmentManger will throw this exception.
**Solution:**  
 To Fix this need to override the restoreState method in our FragmentStatePagerAdapter and put try catch block. It will prevent the crash and also it will retain the viewpager's fragment state for normal case.

```
@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    try {
        super.restoreState(state, loader);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Error Restore State of Fragment : " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

**Note:** We can use FragmentPagerAdapter or Override [saveState](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28091395/2336184)() and return null also fix this issue but viewpager will not retain its state for the normal case.

Comment: Thanks @Vicky, works like charm, this should be marked as the right answer

Comment: cannot override, it is set as final :(

Answer (score 13):

if you are using ViewPager2 then use this method on ViewPager2 object

```
viewPager2.setSaveEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 4):

I have struggle on this problem for whole day, but now I found the solution.

```
private ViewPager _mViewPager;
_mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
//5 is how much page you have.
```

`setOffscreenPageLimit` Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.

Comment: this uses a ton of memory... saves the hassle of not saving the state and all.. but this is bad in the long run when there is a ton of data

Answer (score 2):

Use Activity lifeCycle instead of Fragment.

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    public MyAdapter (@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
        super(fragment.getFragmentManager(), fragment.getActivity().getLifecycle());
    }
}
```

Or as others mentioned disable the `ViewPager2` save state.

- in Layout: `android:saveEnabled="false"`
- in code:

  - `viewPager.setSaveEnabled(false);`
  - `viewPager.setSaveFromParentEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 1):

very good ! Since is  repeat `pager.setAdapter(adapter);` when call `restoreState` cause exception:

```
Fragment no longer exists for key f0: index 0
```

we can Release Fragment RootView

```
    public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    if (isRecyclerRootViewAlways()) {
        mRootView = null;//<--
    }
    mMyFragmentLifecycle.onFragmentDestroyView(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with viewpager2 detach from recyclerview
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154751401

As per my knowledge two fixes are there:

1. add this line in your xml viewpager2 component.

   ```
   android:saveEnabled="false"
   ```

But the above one dont save the current instance, which the fragment will recreate each time it pops back.

2. The recommended solution is add the below line on your fragment

   ```
   override fun onDestroyView() {
      super.onDestroyView()
      viewPager.adapter = null
   }
   ```

Answer (score -5):

Use

> getFragmentManager()

in fragment adapter
not child fragment manager

```
PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
```

I hope this helps.