# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment no longer exists for key f1999: index 1

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

i have encountred this problem and performed folowing solution to fix it but couldnt fix this problem yet. And also i tried to use `fragmentpageradapter` instead of `fragmentstatepageradapter`but still facing same problem.

[java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragement no longer exists for key f1: index 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756102/java-lang-illegalstateexception-fragement-no-longer-exists-for-key-f1-index-3)

this crash happens when i go back to fragment which contains viewpager.

Any idea?

firstly pushing productdetail fragment to "maincontainer"

```
public void switchToProductDetail(SearchHelper searchHelper, Product product)
{
    ProductDetailFragment productDetailFragment = new ProductDetailFragment();
    productDetailFragment.product = product;
    productDetailFragment.searchHelper = searchHelper;
    setNewFragment(productDetailFragment, R.id.mainContainer, "ProductDetail", true, true, true, true);
}
```

and then if user doesnt sign in and pressed to add to fav button, i am pushing signup fragment to "window" container.

```
public void switchtoSignIn(SignInSignUpFragment.SignInCompleteCallBack callBack)
{
    SignInSignUpFragment signInSignUpFragment = new SignInSignUpFragment();
    signInSignUpFragment.callBack = callBack;
    setNewFragment(signInSignUpFragment, R.id.windowFL, "SignIn", true, true, true, true);

}
```

And the mainactivity xml(which contains the maincontainer and windowFL)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/windowFL"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/headerContainer" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mainContainer"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_menu_frame"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/menumargin"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

setnewfragment method is:

```
@SuppressLint("CommitTransaction")
public void setNewFragment(final Fragment fragment, final int containerId, final String tag, final boolean shouldAddBackStack, final boolean shouldReplace, final boolean shouldAnimation, final boolean shouldDrawerClose) {

    if(isAnyMenuOpen() && shouldDrawerClose)
    {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START, true);

        drawerClosedCallBack = new DrawerClosedCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed() {
                setNewFragment(fragment, containerId, tag, shouldAddBackStack, shouldReplace, shouldAnimation, false);
            }
        };

        return;
    }

    if (fragmentManager == null)
    {
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    }

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    if (shouldAnimation)
    {
        if(fragment instanceof SignInSignUpFragment)
        {
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);

        }
        else
        {
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        }
    }

    if (shouldReplace)
    {
        fragmentTransaction.replace(containerId, fragment);

    }
    else
    {
        fragmentTransaction.add(containerId, fragment);
    }

    if(shouldAddBackStack)
    {
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

}
```

Comment: post related code manly your activity

Comment: @Charuක i posted the codes. Thanks